# Manipulating elements added by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dynamically adding a few elements to the DOM.

And I want to manipulate these element with .click() function of jQuery. But somehow DOM is not firing .click() event for dynamically added elements it work just for the other element which are not added by jQuery.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple case of event delegation, means direct event binding on dynamically added elements on a page wont get a event in your case is `click`, so you need to follow a specific syntax for event delegation like:

```
$(staticParent).on(event, selector, callback);
```

Here `staticParent` is the closest parent which holds the dynamically added element that can be a `div, table, form etc.` Event is the event like `click`, selector is the classname or id of element which is in the context and callback is the function which has to run when event happens.

Although `$(document)` is always available for delegating the event. So you can do something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.myElem', function(){
    alert('clicked.');
});
```

Comment: thanks @Jai it works perfectly and i understand it very well ;)

Comment: You are welcome @Youssef. Glad this is a help to you.

Answer (score 1):

Ad Jai already says you need event delegation. In jQuery this can be made with on:
 http://api.jquery.com/on/
 I write this small example for you:

```
$(document).on("click", "input[type='button']", function() {
    alert("clicked");
});

// add two buttons 
$("<input/>", {
    type: "button",
    value: "button"
}).appendTo("#buttonsHolder");

$("<input/>", {
   type: "button",
   value: "button"    
}).appendTo("#buttonsHolder");
```

Here is working jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zono/DXqWe/

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you need to add the click handler after dynamically adding elements.  If the click function is bound to elements before the dynamically added elements, the new elements won't have the click function.

Comment: Check out .on()'s event delegation syntax.