# Manipulating dynamic elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, pug

I have a dropdown menu with values that are generated dynamically through Jade templating. When one of the dropdown menu items is clicked, I want the dropdown header text to update to the text value of the menu item selected, like so:

```
-Select an item:-
    - Item 1
    - Item 2
    - Item 3 

[somebody clicks on item 3...]--->

-Item 3:-
    - Item 1
    - Item 2
    - Item 3
```

Here's my code:

```
$('.selectShow').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).text);
    $('#showSelectDropdown').text($(this).text);
});
```

The console gets a weird undefined JSON object, and if I change the third line to something like `$(#showSelectDropdown).text('hello!');` that works, so I'm assuming it's some problem with the fact that the values are generated dynamically (although it's unclear to me why this is a problem since I'm using jquery and this whole thing is wrapped in a `(document).ready`. I found a similar stackOverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586208/manipulating-elements-added-by-jquery) that suggests using event delegation with the `.on('click)...` selector, but I'm still getting the same results. I'm a little stumped. Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `.text` by `.text()`:

```
$('.selectShow').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
    $('#showSelectDropdown').text($(this).text());
});
```

[See the full `.text()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Dangit you're too fast.

Comment: @JoeFrambach 2+ minutes. It's too long :)

Comment: Wow, what an oversight. Thanks so much!